# How to have a bot reply to another bot's message with inline keyboard?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I have a scenario where my bot starts a conversation with another bot to receive one reply with inline keyboard. How can my bot reply using the inline keyboard?

```
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = 12345
api_hash = "hash123"

with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app:
    app.send_message("otherbot", "Hello")  # This message is received by otherbot, which then triggers a reply that contains an inline keyboard
    # Here I need to reply to otherbot's message
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a Conversation Handler.

> A conversation-like feature is not available yet in Pyrogram. One way to do that is saving states into a dictionary using user IDs as keys. Check the dictionary before taking actions so that you know in which step your users are and update it once they successfully go past one action.

https://t.me/pyrogramchat/213488

(copy-pasted from another answer of mine.)

Comment: Thanks. I found a workaround for my use case and will post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @ColinShark, `pyrogram` does not support Conversation Handler. So, this simple workaround worked for my use case:

```
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = 12345
api_hash = "hash123"
bot_name = "otherbot"

with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app:
    response = app.send_message(bot_name, "Hello")
    bot_reply_msg_id = int(response["message_id"]) + 1

    response = app.get_messages(bot_name, bot_reply_msg_id)
    try:
        response.click(2, timeout=1)  # to click on the third button/option. Index start at 0.
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
```